# add custom middleware to a group

Tags: laravel

The routes defined in "routes/api.php" are supposed to use the "api" middleware group.

However if I add my custom middleware (here "cors"), this one is not being triggered. Why ? :

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            ...
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
            'cors'
        ],
    ];

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
        ...
   ]
```

It only works if I use "cors" globally :

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class
]
```

I only want to use it with api group.

My middleware :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header(
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
                '*'
            )
            ->header(
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
                'X-REQUESTED-WITH'
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: does update like the following works? `'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
            \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
        ],`

Comment: No, I've tried that too.

Comment: Interestingly, if I visit directly my api route in the browser, the "handle" method is triggered. But with my axios request, I get cors blocked. And I don't see any effect of a dd('...') in handle method.    And as I said, my cors middleware works if under global $middleware [].

Comment: Try clearing cache.

Comment: Does any other api specific middlwares work?

Comment: There's only "throttle:60,1" and "bindings".   I comment my cors mw, and add dd() in those api's handle method, and I see the dump in the network response.

Comment: If I use the same origin on front and back end, then my cors middleware is hit. I see the dump.  But if use different origins, it seems thta the cors is blocked before reaching my cors middleware...

Comment: Check whether any other middleware is hit and modifying request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203775/discussion-between-trogne-and-ab-in).

Comment: The request is blocked (cors reject) before reaching the first api group middleware. My conclusion is that, as of laravel 6.6.1, it's still not possible to handle cors in a middleware group. The cors middleware must be added to the $middleware array (global middlewares).

Comment: maybe your middleware has such an issue ... you should probably provide your middleware in your question

Comment: @lagbox, maybe ! I I added my middleware

Comment: Oh, I wanted to test barryvdh/laravel-cors,  so I installed that. But now my middleware works as a group !   What happened ?    Is it possible that installing barrydvh fixed something ?    Did "composer require" did something with "autoload" ?